# Firefox browser display

Tags: html

I'm currently working on a website, and the display appears correctly on Chrome, but Firefox doesn't render everything in the correct positioning (IE actually gets closer than FF does). Can anyone help?

http://www.camberandconcave.com/sample.html

Thanks!

Edit: the code on the site displays on Chrome with hr's separating the three different sections of the page.  On FF, the hr tags display in the top right corner of the page, rather than in the correct locations.

Comment: Please note a specific area you are having trouble with and provide code.

Comment: Alright, added the problem I'm having to the question.  Sorry.

Comment: Oh, no sorry needed, just trying to help you get the best answers possible!

Comment: Try changing the width of the `<hr />`s to `100%` rather than `1000px`. (just a guess)

Comment: Nope, unfortunately that didn't seem to fix it =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `clear: both;` to your hr style in your css.

The problem is that some of your divs are floating left but the ones containing the hr's aren't (I don't think you need the `<hr />`s to be contained in those divs anyway).

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.  I didn't know about the `clear` property.